# How can I make a npm module avaible in browser

Tags: node.js, npm

I made a npm module, it works perfectly in node, but I laso want to make it avaible in browser as Socket.io is. In node I use it that way : `var AIM = require('aimjs')(server)`

server param is optional and is from http.Server ([Node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server)) if specified it serve a client version of the module as Socket.io do :

```
if (this.server != null) {
    var listeners = this.server.listeners('request').slice()
    this.server.removeAllListeners('request')
    this.server.on('request', function (req, res) {
        if (url.parse(req.url).pathname === '/AIM.js') {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript')
          res.writeHead(200)
          res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/AIM.client.js'))
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
        listeners[i].call(self.srv, req, res)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

This file (AIM.client.js) is a browserified version of my main, but the module is not avaible outside. How can I make it global ? I want that users just have to install module, include `<script type='text/javascript' src='/AIM.js'></script>` and can use it both client side and server side.

Answer (score 0):

When you browserify your file, use the `--standalone` (`-s`) option.

Example:

```
browserify index.js -s aimjs
```

This will make your file a UMD bundle.

- If it is used in a CommonJS environment, it will behave as a CommonJS module.
- If it is used in an AMD environment, it will behave as an AMD module.
- If it is simply included via a script tag, it will attach itself to `window.aimjs`.

Comment: It didn't worked so I refactored my code in one single file and made 3 possible export for (amd, window and module)